# How to find all the employees under one manager using a subquery? SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

does anyone know how to create a subquery to find all the employees under one manager? For example if I want to find someone that works on susan jones how would I create the query?

```
 Manager Table: 
 Employee ID    Manager_ID     Name         Title     
 1                 NULL      James Smith    CEO      
 2                  1        Ron Johnson    Sales Manager  
 3                  2        Fred Hobbs     Sales Person    
 4                  1        Susan Jones    Support Manager
```

Comment: under a particular manager, i.e. you will provide a manager id or you want grouping of employees based on manager id?

Comment: is there any hierarchy like `Ron Johnson` has manager `James Smith` but there is another employee whose manager is `Ron Johnson`?

Comment: there is an employee table that groups the employees that classifies them whether they are a manager or a regular worker based on which division they belong too. the employee table looks like this: 
employee_id, division_id, job_id, first_name, last_name, salary

Answer (score 0):

```
select employeename,managerid
from manager
where manager_id is not null
group by employeename ,manager_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, supposing the table for employees is simply named Employee and its key is named 'Employee_ID' (like in the Manger table), then you just need to use a simple Join:

```
SELECT e.* FROM Employee AS e JOIN Manger AS m ON e.Employee_ID=m.Employee_ID WHERE m.Name='Susan Jones'
```